# Google Fonts' CSS is lying about its WOFF2 files: How can I know that in runtime/while rendering?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, google-font-api

### Context

I'm working on an app that needs to dynamically analyze and apply fonts from Google Fonts. Part of that consists of reading the `unicode-range` CSS property to: first, get to know which characters a given font includes (this is the actual pain point/lie); second, render those characters with that font.

### The Problem

A given `unicode-range` might list code points that **are not included**/covered with glyphs by its respective WOFF2 files.

I did realize that by a) visually testing it: characters will render with a given fallback font (usually `serif` if there's no fallback); or b) by requesting a font specifying *included but actually missing* characters as the `text` value on its URL: in such a case Google Fonts use to return CSS with broken WOFF2 URLs.

### The Question(s)

1. Is there any JavaScript/CSS API we can use to know when a character is rendered by a fallback font?
2. Is Google Fonts automating its CSS building process in such a way that `unicode-range`(s) are likely to always include some missing code points?

### Example

For the sake of simplicity I'm not going to bring here all the code I came up with to automate the following process because it's out of scope.

Roboto includes the following characters on its `cyrillic-ext` subset:

```
Ԕ ԕ Ԗ ԗ Ԙ ԙ Ԛ ԛ Ԝ ԝ Ԟ ԟ Ԡ ԡ
Ԣ ԣ Ԥ ԥ Ԧ ԧ Ԩ ԩ Ԫ ԫ Ԭ ԭ Ԯ ԯ
```

Here we have those characters (actually not) rendering with Roboto:

```css
/* cyrillic-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}

.fallback--serif {
  font-family: Roboto, serif;
}

.fallback--sans-serif {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.fallback--monospace {
  font-family: Roboto, monospace;
}
```

```html
<p class="fallback--serif">
  <code>serif</code> fallback<br/> Ԕ ԕ Ԗ ԗ Ԙ ԙ Ԛ ԛ Ԝ ԝ Ԟ ԟ Ԡ ԡ<br/> Ԣ ԣ Ԥ ԥ Ԧ ԧ Ԩ ԩ Ԫ ԫ Ԭ ԭ Ԯ ԯ
</p>
<p class="fallback--sans-serif">
  <code>sans-serif</code> fallback<br/> Ԕ ԕ Ԗ ԗ Ԙ ԙ Ԛ ԛ Ԝ ԝ Ԟ ԟ Ԡ ԡ<br/> Ԣ ԣ Ԥ ԥ Ԧ ԧ Ԩ ԩ Ԫ ԫ Ԭ ԭ Ԯ ԯ
</p>
<p class="fallback--monospace">
  <code>monospace</code> fallback<br/> Ԕ ԕ Ԗ ԗ Ԙ ԙ Ԛ ԛ Ԝ ԝ Ԟ ԟ Ԡ ԡ<br/> Ԣ ԣ Ԥ ԥ Ԧ ԧ Ԩ ԩ Ԫ ԫ Ԭ ԭ Ԯ ԯ
</p>
```

Comment: It isn't lying, `unicode-range` is a hint set by the client for the browser so that it doesn't download the font in case no character in that range is displayed. It doesn't mean that every character in that range is supported. Unfortunately there isn't a proper way to check if a font will render a character, even though [this comment](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/6798#issuecomment-962079873) states it should be possible to hack something around, I failed to got it working (didn't spent too much time on it either).

Comment: It's telling something that is not true, by definition that's a lie or a mistake. Don't worry, the "lying" was only for the title. Call it an innocent mistake if you will. I do know how the `unicode-range` works. I just wonder that, if Google Fonts creates the CSS for a given font file: it should be able to do it right; because it's generating useless code by faking content it doesn't have, probably leading to bugs as it does in my app. I think they can do it better, so they should.

Comment: But the glyphs that this font file does handle *are* in this unicode-range, aren't they? That's all that's implied by this code. They could have made the importer file bigger by making the range narrower to the point it would state all the glyphs the font handles, but then this `unicode-range` rule would become so big that its whole purpose (to avoid useless network data consumption) would be defeated. That would be a "lie" only if they did set it to a range that doesn't encompass any of the supported glyphs.

Comment: I understand you. however, notice that the ranges **are** actually narrowed. They do not point to "the range", e.g.: `cyrillic-ext = U+0500–052F`, they point to multiple subsegments of several subsets. Then they could be even shorter, not necessarily larger. Also, notice this is only one example: because of that specificity, some `unicode-range` values weight **more than 2 KB**, that's 2000 characters. The example has only 72.